# How to do a calculation of a new parameter within an Oracle SQL Function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm trying to calculate the balance due in this function using some values that are in the Invoice table. I'm not quite sure where exactly to place the calculation line. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Create or Replace Function Get_balance_due(
f_invoice_id In Number)
Return Number
AS
    balance_due Number;
    f_invoice_total Number;
    f_payment_total Number;
    f_credit_total Number;


Begin
    select (vendor_id into f_vendor_id,
    invoice total into f_invoice_total,
    payment_total into f_payment_total,
    credit_total into f_credit_total)

From
    invoices
Where
    invoice_id = f_invoice_id
    balance_due = f_invoice_total - f_payment_total - f_credit_total;
Return (balance_due);
End;
/
SHOW ERRORS Function Get_balance_due;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION get_balance_due(
         f_invoice_id IN NUMBER)
         RETURN NUMBER
AS
     balance_due NUMBER;
     f_invoice_total NUMBER;
     f_payment_total NUMBER;
     f_credit_total NUMBER;

BEGIN
     SELECT invoice total, payment_total, credit_total
     INTO  f_invoice_total, f_payment_total, f_credit_total
     FROM  invoices
     WHERE invoice_id = f_invoice_id;

     balance_due := f_invoice_total - f_payment_total - f_credit_total;

RETURN balance_due;
END;
```